# Cannot open file after fork-exec

Tags: c++, file-io, exec, fork

I'm writing some code with a fork-exec pattern, and the child process is meant to open a file in the /tmp directory (append-create mode) to write its output to. (The file does not exist in advance, but is created upon open, or at least it should be...) However, I'm finding that the child cannot open any file after exec. It can open/create a file and write to it after fork and before exec, but after exec I find that the file doesn't get created. Furthermore, if I run the program I'm exec'ing (with the same argument) on the command line, it creates the file and writes to it just fine. Only when it's started from exec does it seem to have this problem. I really have no idea how to start thinking about this problem... If anyone has suggestions on where to look for clues, I'd really appreciate it!

Here's a rough example - note this is not actual code that runs  :)
Child:

```
#define MSG "Opened file: "
int main (usual stuff) {
    const char* szTemp = "/tmp/helloworld";
    FILE* temp = fopen(szTemp, "a");
    fwrite(MSG, sizeof(char), strlen(MSG), temp);
    fwrite(szTemp, sizeof(char), strlen(szTemp), temp);
    fwrite("\n", sizeof(char), 1, temp);
    fclose(temp);
    // at this point, I see the file with the normal content when Child is run
    // from the command line, but the file is not created if Child is created
    // by a call to exec
}
```

Parent:

```
int main(usual stuff) {
    pid_t pid = fork();
    if (0 == pid) {
        // fopen/fwrite works fine if I do it here!
        exec(child-process);
    }
    // parent continues...
}
```

Comment: Posting your code might lead to useful responses.

Comment: I added some illustrative code...  My actual code is ~20,000 lines for the entire system, and as I said I'm quite flummoxed and don't know where to start looking for the problem, so I wouln't know which small subset of all that code to share with you. If anyone has a suggestion on where I should start looking, I can try to provide some code along those lines...

Comment: I think you need to make a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). Odds are you will find the actual problem in the process of making a small example to show us the problem. As it is, I know that it's possible to write a correct program that works as you describe, so all we can really do is guess at what might be going wrong in that 20,000 lines of code.

Comment: I completely agree - that is my usual approach. However, getting there from something this complicated could take a rather lot of work (i.e., a long time) and I'm on a deadline, so I strongly suspect that will take more time than I have. I was hoping maybe someone had seen something like this before, or else knows enough of the inner working of `fork()` and `exec()` and Linux process and file management that they could offer some speculation...

Comment: @Casey PS - Thank you for being constructive with your comment, though! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I figured it out!  Here's what happened: The code that touches the file before exec is called obviously ran and did what it's supposed to. The code that touches the file as soon as main starts didn't touch the file because it never ran. The process died between exec and main!

There are a number of ways this can happen, but in my case it was because it was trying to load a shared object (.so) file (the Linux flavor of dynamically linked libraries) but the path wasn't in LD_LIBRARY_PATH so it failed. (Everything worked fine from the command line because my LD_LIBRARY_PATH did include the correct directory there, but my process starting from fork didn't have access to that environment...) The solution is to simply use the evnironment parameter of exec to pass in a correct value for LD_LIBRARY_PATH, and then the child process can find the .so file and start up properly.

And now, here's why it was hard to detect in this case... Normally if a process can't find a necessary .so when it's startin up, it give you a message (on stderr, I believe) letting you know exactly which library it couldn't find. My trouble was that the parent process is a daemon, so I had closed stdin, stdout, and stderr. When I fork, the child inherits open file descriptors, but since the standard streams were closed, it did not have anywhere to send its output. Once I added code to make the child processes send stdout & stderr to a file (this is done between fork and exec), I was able to see the error message in the output file.

I got kinda lucky here, though, because I was adding output for stdout/stderr for (mostly) unrelated reasons...